# AngularJS routes and template loading

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create a single page app with angularjs to which I'm very new.  I've pieced together this code based on a number of tutorials, but it doesn't work and I'm not quite sure why.  I'm not getting any errors that I can see.  The intention is to have the home.html file load on the initial load. Then based on the routes, load in different templates.

script.js

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/view", {
        templateUrl: "/view.html",
        controller: "ViewCtrl"
    })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl: "/home.html",
        controller: "HomeCtrl"
    });
}]);

angular.module("myApp").controller("ViewCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "In the view";
}]);

angular.module("myApp").controller("HomeCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "At home";
}]);

angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.4" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.4.0-beta.4" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content" ng-app="myApp"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

home.html

```
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    {{message}}
</div>
```

view.html

```
<div ng-controller="ViewCtrl">
  {{message}}
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eLZQueX3OyPCXo2tQGWS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of mistakes in your code. Please look the below changes

1) Add `ng-view` directive for loading partial content

```
<div id="content" ng-app="myApp"></div>

should be

<div id="content" ng-app="myApp" ng-view></div>
```

2) Template url not starts with slash (/)

```
templateUrl: "/view.html",
templateUrl: "/home.html",

Should be

templateUrl: "view.html",
templateUrl: "home.html",
```

3) No need to bootstrap the app manually, `ng-app` automatically do this.

4) No need to mention the controller in router level if you mentioned in template (vice versa)

Working Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/n19eCFwRc9WQUt6SskPU?p=preview

Comment: And there should not be any ng-controller on the views, since the router already instantiates the controller and associates it to the view. And there's no need to manually bootstrap the app, since that's what ng-app does.

Comment: @JB Nizzet, yes answer updated as per your valid comment. thank you!